# Reducing Identity cookie size in .NET Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

so here's my situation:

I have a .NET Core 2.0 web app which using Identity and Google auth. Claims retrieved from Google login are email, first name, last name, and domain.

Here's where I run in to some trouble. I also use the Google Directory service to obtain the user's email groups. These groups are used as roles for authorization within the app which get stored as claims, thus making the Identity cookie larger.

When someone has a ton of Google Groups, the cookie actually ends up being too big and gives the user a 502.3 error on our websites. Is there any way to reduce the size of the cookie? I know the issue lies within the Google Groups getting stored as claims. Is there another way to store them using the Identity framework that doesn't effect the cookie?

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do about it if they're being added as roles. It would take a *ton* of Groups to cause a problem, but that threshold is present. You may need to not treat them as roles, and instead simply create a relationship with the user that you can query (i.e. persist it to the database instead). You'll then need to add some manual logic to check Google Group membership, instead of relying on `Authorize`.

Comment: Cookie auth has an alternate way to store identities where you cache the principal locally and send the client a small identifier. See this sample: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/272aa16322f25f6c054598bdc06e7518ed0212fa/samples/CookieSessionSample/Startup.cs#L22